# Ruby Rails Execjs : How to create external runtime utilitizing bun.sh?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, execjs, bun

I would like to run javascript code in my ruby program. But it is very slow, so I would try to use bun.sh instead of nodejs as a runtime in execjs.

How can I achieve that ?

---

I tried this:

```rb
require 'execjs'
require "execjs/external_runtime"

PATH_TO_JS = File.join(__dir__, "/katex.min.js")
BUN = ExternalRuntime.new(
      name:        "Bun",
      command:     ["bun run"],
      #runner_path: ExecJS.root + "/support/node_runner.js",
      encoding:    'UTF-8'
)
KATEX = BUN.compile(open(PATH_TO_JS).read)
```

But I got this error:

```
project.rb:10:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ExternalRuntime (NameError)
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

It must be under `ExecJS::ExternalRuntime`